# SQL Server Utilizar una Secuencia con incremente mayor a uno

Tags: sql, sql-server

he querido realizar un insert en SQL Server 2017 y tengo una secuencia con incremente de 50 por ejemplo:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE producto.numero_orden
AS INT
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 50;
```

Al utilizar la secuencia en el insert:

```
INSERT INTO producto.orden_compra
    (orden_id,
    vendedor_id,
    fecha_orden)
VALUES
    (NEXT VALUE FOR producto.numero_orden,1,'2019-04-30');
```

Lo que sucede en este caso es que cada `INSERT` aumentaría en 50, siendo el primero 50 y el según do 100, es posible solicitar el incremento en 1 al momento de realizar el `INSERT` sin modificar la secuencia.

Comment: No, a menos de que no uses la secuencia.

Comment: Según lo que pides puedes realizar el insert pero sería una query aparte, puedes insertar en la tabla sin afectar la secuencia dando un valor fijo.